# NodeJs: no response to NPM install

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install the express framework for node.js. However, whenever i run "sudo npm install express", i never get a response. It just sits there. Im seriously frustrated at this point.

Using npm 1.0.22 on OSX Lion

Comment: which version of npm do you have, where did you install it from, and which os are you running?

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue on lion as well. It was because Lion removed xcode from my path and at some point, the express install triggered gcc.

Try this to pinpoint your problem, it will turn on [verbose npm output](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel) and is a great way to debug npm packages:
`npm config set loglevel info`

If your problem does turn out to be a lack of gcc, first see if it's already installed in:  **/Developer/usr/bin** and if not, use the 'app store' to reinstall.

Here's more info on the gcc issue: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-path-for-gcc-in-Mac-OS-X-Lion

Answer (score 1):

You may be running node v0.5.5-pre which doesn't fall within the required version numbers for the npm package. I found some "answers" [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/819).
To fix I downloaded the 0.4.11 tar.gz from the node.js main page and did a manual build/install: (./configure ; sudo make install) and ran npm install express again, which worked fine this time.